# Close Reason for Poll Questions

Tags: support, close-reasons

My more general question is what is the best close-reason for questions you feel are rep whoring or just simply unwarranted?

Usually they are poll-style questions like: "When did you start programming?" or something like that.

The OP only *technically* meets all the criteria of a question but you feel it shouldn't be on the site nonetheless (see the above example). I often find myself looking for a "Misc" reason to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Not a real question" fits the bill pretty well, so long as you consider a "real" question to be one where the OP actually wants an answer vs. merely a list of responses + votes.

Comment: That's a good point. A question mark does not a question make.

Comment: Now when people say "you shouldn't close as 'not a real question' -- if polls were bad there would be a 'close as poll' option" I look back on this and weep

Answer (score 3):

I've said repeatedly that I hate blatant poll questions. I hate them more than questions that actually have extended discussion (something that tends to be more frowned upon).

I would love if there was a "closed as poll" reason so I could go and start murdering some posts.

Answer (score 2):

Just go with your gut. For instance, just because the question says "When did you start programming" I would not consider it programming related. It isn't about how to program. It is not solving a programming problem.

Comment: They're.

Comment: Got it. Making the change below.

Comment: That was my first instinct. But I feel like they caught me on a technicality... Like when you send a kid to their room without television. They're not watching television but they're playing XBox.

Comment: @rcartaino, my response to that would be they *are* watching television, but they're not watching television *programming* (shows/movies). A television is the device itself :)