# People want to close my question just because it reminds them of boat programming!

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

I've recently asked:

[Boat academics: Are there any academic institutions operating on bodies of water?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90392/boat-academics-are-there-any-academic-institutions-operating-on-bodies-of-water?noredirect=1#comment230064_90392)

This is a perfectly legitimate question with some interesting answers. In fact, I might actually go visit one of these when I'm next in California or in Venice. It has also gotten quite a few upvotes for the question and for answers.

Unfortunately, some mean-spirited spoil-sports are marking the question for closure since it reminds them of "boat programming". That's not fair! Why am I to blame for that meme? If the meme had been "hot-air-balloon programming", nobody would have said anything about my question.

Also, if I deny this question is inspired by "boat programming", people won't believe me, and if I state it is, people would use that as another excuse to close it.

What should I do?

Comment: People want to close that question **because it is a poll**.

Comment: Belongs [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Please explain how one is to choose the most correct answer to your question?

Comment: If every single different answer is valid and has the same chance of being accepted, consider that the question is not suitable for this platform.

Comment: @Oded: The correct answer to the question is "Yes, here's a proper example" or "No, there is no XYZ". I did indicate I'd accept something "close enough", so I'm waiting for the best "close enough" answer and also trying to figure out exactly what people are linking to (e.g. "semester at sea" doesn't sound like a "university a sea").

Comment: @Oded: So, no, it's not a poll.

Comment: Why are you complaining about this here instead of on the local meta? This has nothing to do with SE as a whole. I also agree that it's not a useful question, but the final word lies with the Academia.se community so I don't understand why you'd post here.

Comment: I think the OP has a somewhat valid concern here, and I think the "boat programming" comments there are a bit off (although, honestly, Mr. Richerby tends to follow HNQ's around and can generally be ignored). But still, yes, this needs to be on Academia Meta, as what they define as a "poll" or how they feel about such questions is entirely their community-specific policy.

Comment: @terdon: Because I'm complaining about an issue that's not specific to academia.SX - that meme is not from academia.SX

Comment: Yes, but the reaction of the academia community to your question is specific to Academia.se and that's what you want to discuss. There's nothing anyone here can tell you that would be relevant. But never mind, this has been closed here, so just take your case to meta.academia where the people who can actually help you can be found.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anything about programming, boats or academics.

As such I'm probably the perfect person to not think of it as programming on a boat. What I do see is it's [essentially a polling question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186530/what-close-reason-for-polling-questions). It's also what I tend to class as a 'soft' guessing game question where people are trying to find something that matches incredibly broad criteria. It's  like walking into a bookstore and asking for a book about shearing sheep in Australia.

As such, if you were asking about Academic Institutions operating in outer space, and I had enough reputation, I would be inclined to close it too.

Comment: How is it a polling question if it asks "Does any X exist"?

Comment: To me, that's the very definition of a polling question, and I'd be inclined to close it as too broad. Assuming I could vote there, which I can't

Comment: One *might* be able to argue that the answer set is narrow enough that it may not count as a "poll" in this sense (but I can't really make this argument myself, I don't know the answers), but really that's up to the Academia community to figure out.

Comment: Yes. Imagine the question was "are there any universities with buildings that are more than X years old?" or "are there any universities with buildings that are good examples of [Art Deco or Brutalism or Postmodern] architecture?" or "are there any universities located less than an hour from excellent [mountain climbing or scuba diving or Michelin-starred restaurants]?" These are all interesting things to wonder but they are not good StackExchange questions. Nothing to do with boats.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Actually, there's an explicit "very definition" of a polling question, which is what got pasted on my question: """Shopping" questions, which seek recommendations or lists of individual universities, academic programs, publishers, journals, research topics or similar as an answer or seek an assessment or comparison of such, are off-topic here." - and my question does not meet them. Neither would a question about whether there are any universities in outer space.